# Possible to open modal from outside the vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to call a method from outside the component to make the component reuseable?

Right now I add my button to open the modal in a template slot:

`index.php`

```
<modal>
    <template slot="button">
        <button class="btn">Open modal</button>
    </template>
    Some modal text
</modal>
```

`Modal.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div @click="showModal"><slot name="button"></slot></div>
        <div v-if="showingModal"><slot></slot></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data () {
            return {
                showingModal: false,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            showModal() {
                this.showingModal = true;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

I feel like there is an better option but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 18):

> Yes,you can call a method from outside the component!

**Parent component**

```
<template>
 <div>
   <modal ref="modal"></modal>
   <button @click="openModal">Open Modal</button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import modal from './child.vue'
  export default {
    components: { modal }
    methods: {
     openModal() { this.$refs.modal.show() }//executing the show method of child
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Child component**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="showModal">
    <div id="modal">
      <p>Hello i am a modal
      </p>
      <button @click="hide">Close</button>
    </div> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   data() {
     return {
      showModal: false
     }
   },
   methods: {
     show() {
      this.showModal = true
     },
     hide(){
      this.showModal = false
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/75073kLx/)

Answer (score 4):

Put you `modal` component instance into `Vue.prototype`, then invoke `show/hide` at anywhere you can access `Vue` instance context.

**Below is one demo:**

```js
let vm = null // the instance for your Vue modal
let timeout = null //async/delay popup

const SModal = {
  isActive: false,

  show ({
    delay = 500,
    message = '',
    customClass = 'my-modal-class'
  } = {}) {
    if (this.isActive) {
      vm && vm.$forceUpdate()
      return
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null

      const node = document.createElement('div')
      document.body.appendChild(node)
      let staticClass = ''
      vm = new this.__Vue({
        name: 's-modal',
        el: node,
        render (h) { // uses render() which is a closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates
          return h('div', {
            staticClass,
            'class': customClass,
            domProps: {
              innerHTML: message
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }, delay)

    this.isActive = true
  },
  hide () {
    if (!this.isActive) {
      return
    }

    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      timeout = null
    } else {
      vm.$destroy()
      document.body.removeChild(vm.$el)
      vm = null
    }

    this.isActive = false
  },

  __Vue: null,
  __installed: false,
  install ({ $my, Vue }) {
    if (this.__installed) { return }
    this.__installed = true
    $my.SModal = SModal // added your SModal object to $my
    this.__Vue = Vue //get the Vue constructor
  }
}

let installFunc = function (_Vue, opts = {}) {
  if (this.__installed) {
    return
  }
  this.__installed = true
  const $my = {
    'memo': 'I am a plugin management.'
  }
  if (opts.plugins) {
    Object.keys(opts.plugins).forEach(key => {
      const p = opts.plugins[key]
      if (typeof p.install === 'function') {
        p.install({ $my, Vue: _Vue })
      }
    })
  }
  _Vue.prototype.$my = $my
}

Vue.use(installFunc, {
  plugins: [SModal]
})

app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    'test 1': 'Cat in Boots'
  },
  methods: {
    openModal: function () {
      this.$my.SModal.show({'message':'test', 'delay':1000})
    },
    closeModal: function () {
      this.$my.SModal.hide()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-modal-class {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:20px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="openModal()">Open Modal!!!</button>
    <button @click="closeModal()">Close Modal!!!</button>
</div>
```

**Rough Steps for vue-cli project:**

**In ./plugins/SModal.js** (follow the tutorial in official document to create one vue instance then add it into the `document.body`):

```
let vm = null // the instance for your Vue modal
let timeout = null //async/delay popup

const SModal = {
  isActive: false,

  show ({
    delay = 500,
    message = '',
    customClass = ''
  } = {}) {
    if (this.isActive) {
      vm && vm.$forceUpdate()
      return
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null

      const node = document.createElement('div')
      document.body.appendChild(node)

      vm = new this.__Vue({
        name: 's-modal',
        el: node,
        render (h) { // uses render() which is a closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates
          return h('div', {
            staticClass,
            'class': props.customClass
          })
        }
      })
    }, delay)

    this.isActive = true
  },
  hide () {
    if (!this.isActive) {
      return
    }

    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      timeout = null
    } else {
      vm.$destroy()
      document.body.removeChild(vm.$el)
      vm = null
    }

    this.isActive = false
  },

  __Vue: null,
  __installed: false,
  install ({ $my, Vue }) {
    if (this.__installed) { return }
    this.__installed = true
    $my.SModal = SModal // added your SModal object to $my
    this.__Vue = Vue //get the Vue constructor
  }
}

export default SModal
```

As [the official document said](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), A Vue.js plugin should expose an install method. The method will be called with the Vue constructor as the first argument, along with possible options

**In install.js** (also you can move this method into main.js based on your design):

```
// loop all plugins under the folder ./plugins/, then install it.
export default function (_Vue, opts = {}) {
  if (this.__installed) {
    return
  }
  this.__installed = true
  const $my = {
    'memo': 'I am a plugin management.'
  }
  if (opts.plugins) {
    Object.keys(opts.plugins).forEach(key => {
      const p = opts.plugins[key]
      if (typeof p.install === 'function') {
        p.install({ $my, Vue: _Vue })
      }
    })
  }

  _Vue.prototype.$my = $my
}
```

**In main.js** (finally uses your plugins):

```
import install from './install'
import * as plugins from './plugins'

Vue.use({ install }, {
  plugins
})
```

**Finally** in your view/component, you can show/hide your modal like this:

```
this.$my.SModal.show()
this.$my.SModal.hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, accept a property to the modal component:

```
 props: ['open']
```

Then pass it in:

```
<modal :open="boolToOpenModal"> ... </modal>
```

Then:

```
<div v-if="showingModal || open"><slot></slot></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no (easy, supported) way to call a method in a component, but you can either modify a property in the child (eg. `show`) (see [Passing Data to Child Components with Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)) or use events (see [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) and [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)). Using events you could also use an [event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). The event based solution is of course better suited to more complex interactions.

Answer (score 0):

I simply add `v-on="$listeners"` to the component in the children (modal.vue):

```
// modal.vue
<template>
   <div :show="show" v-on="$listeners">
     ...
   </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        show: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    ...
```

Now you can open or close the modal from its parent easily:

```
//parent.vue
<modal @close="showModal = false" :show="showModal" />
```