# Launch a Vue modal component outside of a SPA context

Tags: vue.js

We're in the process of retrofitting a mature website with some updated forms. We're replacing some systems entirely with SPAs and some just don't warrant it.

However, we have some system-global modal screens that we need to be available. Some of these have been ported to Vue and work well enough inside SPAs and we'd like to reap the benefits of heightened interactivity in our non-SPA pages.

So whereas before we would have had our event bound like so:

```
$('a.newBooking').on('click', function(ev){
    // code to open bootstrap modal screen, download HTML, etc.
});
```

How do we spin up a component?

I know I haven't included any serious code here but our modals are basically just embellished versions of the [documented example modal component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html). The difference is we don't have the button. We'll want to be able to launch these modals from all around the page.

Comment: Could be done with a message Bus that you pass to all vue components and attach to `window`. In the legacy code you replace the bootstrap code with `window.bus.$emit("open-model-a")` and then in the Vue component that defines your model viability you listen to the bus and react accordingly to show/hide models. Same principle applies if you want to pass the state changes via Vuex. 

If you actually want to just spin up a Vue Component outside the rest of the app, you can just create an instance and mount it whereever; that is exactly what you do in the main SPA root anyway

Comment: something like [Vue Single instance Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50030740/5665870) ? You can access the modal anywhere of your app.

Comment: How are you showing this modal? When you have no button? With display:none | display:block? Or?

Comment: It seems to me that it is not totally clear what you ask help for. My understanding is that you already have a Vue component that provides the modal; you use it in SPA's, but you would like to re-use it as-is in non-SPA. In that case, first step would be to [process your Vue component so that it can be easily consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50695532/5108796) in your non-SPA; then how to setup your non-SPA (you might be interested in [converting your component into a Custom Element](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element)); finally how to configure your listeners to open the modal.

Answer (score 1):

**My opinion:**

***For your Modal components:***

1. use singleton pattern for your modal (because basically we only allow one modal popup at the same time), it will make the logic more simple.
2. customize one install function to add the Vue instances of your Modals to `Vue.prototype`, like `_Vue.prototype.$my = yourModals`
3. then register your plugins in demand like `Vue.use(installFunc, {plugins: [SModal, AModal, BModal]})`

***At your JQuery (or other non-Vue) Apps:***

1. Register Modals to Vue, then create Vue instance
2. show or hide your modals like `vueInstance.$my.SModal.show`

**Below is one simple demo**:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/*---Modal Plugin---*/
let vm = null // the instance for your Vue modal
let timeout = null //async/delay popup

const SModal = {
  isActive: false,

  show ({
    delay = 500,
    message = '',
    customClass = 'my-modal-class'
  } = {}) {
    if (this.isActive) {
      vm && vm.$forceUpdate()
      return
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null

      const node = document.createElement('div')
      document.body.appendChild(node)
      let staticClass = ''
      vm = new this.__Vue({
        name: 's-modal',
        el: node,
        render (h) { // uses render() which is a closer-to-the-compiler alternative to templates
          return h('div', {
            staticClass,
            'class': customClass,
            domProps: {
              innerHTML: message
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }, delay)

    this.isActive = true
  },
  hide () {
    if (!this.isActive) {
      return
    }

    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      timeout = null
    } else {
      vm.$destroy()
      document.body.removeChild(vm.$el)
      vm = null
    }

    this.isActive = false
  },

  __Vue: null,
  __installed: false,
  install ({ $my, Vue }) {
    if (this.__installed) { return }
    this.__installed = true
    $my.SModal = SModal // added your SModal object to $my
    this.__Vue = Vue //get the Vue constructor
  }
}

/*---Modal Plugin End---*/

/*---Custom Install Function in order to manage all modals---*/
let installFunc = function (_Vue, opts = {}) {
  if (this.__installed) {
    return
  }
  this.__installed = true
  const $my = {
    'memo': 'I am a plugin management.'
  }
  if (opts.plugins) {
    Object.keys(opts.plugins).forEach(key => {
      const p = opts.plugins[key]
      if (typeof p.install === 'function') {
        p.install({ $my, Vue: _Vue })
      }
    })
  }
  _Vue.prototype.$my = $my
}

/*---Install Plugins---*/
Vue.use(installFunc, {
  plugins: [SModal]
})

let globalVue = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app'
})

$('#test').on('click', 'span', function () {
  globalVue.$my.SModal.isActive ? globalVue.$my.SModal.hide() :  globalVue.$my.SModal.show({'message':'test', 'delay':100})
})
```

```css
span {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:red;
}

.my-modal-class {
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:150px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app">
</div>
<div id="test">
  <h3>One Example</h3>
  <p><span>Hello</span>, how are you?</p>
  <p>Me? I'm <span>good</span>.</p>
</div>
```