# How to render a modal that is inside a component from another component in vueJs and Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, components, frontend

I have a modal inside a Vue component. Now, from another component i want to show that modal(component) when an event happens(click in a button).
[This is the code of the component(modal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVZjv.png)

[This is the component where i want to get the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv1UZ.png)

Code of the component with the modal

```
    <template>
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modificar Registro Documento</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="false">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modificarRegistro()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" scoped>
export default {
    name : "Modal"
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>

</style>
```

This is the code of the component where i want to get the modal

```
<template>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <div id="padre">
      <div id="barra">
           <Modal/>
        <div v-if="producto === 'bebidas'" class="tabcontent">
        <div>
          <button v-on:click="modal()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
            <h6>Inka Kola</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/incakolaPersonal.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Coca Kola</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/cocaKolaPersona.png" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Sprite</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/sprite.webp" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Cielo</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/cieloPersonal.webp" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>San Mateo</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/sanmateoPersonal.webp" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Ruskalla</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/ruskalla.webp" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Ron</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/ron.webp" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Cristal</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/cristal.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="producto === 'carnes'" class="tabcontent">
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Pollo</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/pollo.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Carne</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/carne.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Cerdo</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/cerdo.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="producto === 'tuberculos'" class="tabcontent">
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Papa</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/papa.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Yuca</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/yuca.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Olluco</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/olluco.webp" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>
            <h6>Jengibre</h6>
            <img src="../../assets/jengibre.jpg" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
#contenedor
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  #padre
    width: 100%
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: center
    #barra
      margin-top: 40px
      display: flex
      button
        border-radius: 0px 
    .tabcontent
      background-color: #999999 
      display: flex
      flex-wrap: wrap
      justify-content: space-around
      width: 100%
      height: 100%
      div
        margin: 20px
        flex-grow: 1
      button
        border: 0px
      img
        width: 100px
        height: 120px
</style>



<script>

import Modal from "./Modal";
export default {  
  name: "Barra",
  data: function () {
    return {
      producto: "bebidas",
      modalEstado : false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    mostrar: function (a) {
      this.producto = a;
        },
    modal(){
      this.modalEstado=true;
      console.log(this.modalEstado);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to open modal from outside the vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027090/possible-to-open-modal-from-outside-the-vue-component)

Comment: No, it didn't. :c